Excel crash when looping over large range to update cells using a function call
I have a loop to update cells using a visual studio dll. This works, but excel crashes when I loop over larger (200 cell) ranges. The dll function is evaluated after looking up two parameters for each distinct cell. The function call is slow but will work for all the parameters supplied for any cells of the range. I can run it for RANGE(N100:W110) and for RANGE(N110:W119) but it crashes when I try RANGE(N100:W119). I'm running with 32bit excel as I need to give it to users with both 32bit and 64bit versions.
Here's my macro:

Sub updatecurves()

Dim curvesheet As Worksheet
Dim My_setcell, c As Range
Dim My_invua, My_uascale, My_uyscale, My_beta, My_sigma, My_KD, My_zD, My_nint, My_nstehfest, My_flag
Dim Neuman72
Dim MyMsg
Set curvesheet = Sheets("neuman72 vs Aq")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

My_uascale = Application.Evaluate(Names("uascale").Value)
My_uyscale = Application.Evaluate(Names("uyscale").Value)
My_sigma = 0.0001
My_KD = Application.Evaluate(Names("KD").Value)
My_zD = Application.Evaluate(Names("zD").Value)
My_nint = Application.Evaluate(Names("testnint").Value)
My_nstehfest = Application.Evaluate(Names("nstehfest").Value)
My_flag = Application.Evaluate(Names("flag").Value)



For Each c In curvesheet.Range("N100:W110").Cells
 
 My_invua = Cells(c.Row, "A").Value
 My_beta = Cells("2", c.Column)
 Neuman72 = Neuman72ForEXL(My_invua, My_uascale, My_uyscale, My_beta, My_sigma, My_KD, My_zD, My_nint, My_nstehfest, My_flag) + expint(1 / (4 * My_invua))
 c.Value = Neuman72
 
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

' some comments

End Sub



Welcome to SO. What is the code for Neuman72ForEXL? Why do you declare almost all variables as Variant instead of specific types? Also, did you try setting the calculation mode into manual, update, and the calculation mode into automatic again?

Thank you for your interest. I have not tried setting calculation mode to manual during execution as I thought that without updating it would not be changing the sheet..? The code for Neuman72ForEXL is a compiled dll from Visual Studio - it is q long as it is an integration of an inverse Laplace Transform function (not very efficiently coded) - about 200 lines. I'll try switching calculation modes...

OK - Dim'ed the variables passed to the function as Double or Long, switched Calculation to xlManual and EnableEvents to false before function (and back after) and get same issue. Symptom is still there - ie it works on the two 100 cell ranges but not on the bigger range

What do you mean with "crashes"? Runtime error? Excel quits completely? Is it related to the call of the DLL? Is it really related to a larger number of data that you process or is it that maybe one of the cells you are processing contains invalid data that isn't handled correctly (eg an empty cell, a cell that contains a string instead of a number, a number that is outside of a valid range...).

Sounds like the issue is in the DLL itself, not Excel.  Updating 200 cells with VBA should be piece of cake unless the calculus is really complex and ponderous. Check what @FunThomas suggested and make sure all of the 200 values are correct. Also, try debugging your step by step so you can see in what exact loop your code crashes.

The crash symptom is that after a few minutes of the 'spinning wheel' busy symbol,  excel disappears and then restarts with last saved version. It seems to be the size of the range that it has an issue with, as the two sub ranges cover all the cells of the larger range, and they evaluate correctly for each sub-range. I switched off most add-ins to try and save memory. When I tried to update the full range (N3:W119) I got an 'available resources' error message. The sheet has a two large scatter (with smooth lines) graphs of the curves with 22 curves in one and 16 curves in the other

The values it calculates are correct, when it tries to do 300, using a different loop structure, it correctly calculates them, gives me a msgbox to let me know, loads the values, gives me another msgbox to say its all done, and then hangs with cells all filled with Gray or black, and unreproducably displays the upadated (correct) graph - does seem to have an issue with working hard! For 300 cells I'm estimating up to 30051264000000 function evaluations (typically exp functions) + 300100 more called to same dll with different entry to a second exported function. It gets each result in ~0.5s

For 300 cells I'm estimating up to 30051264000000* I don't know the exact content of your tool but if you need to do more than 3 billion operations per single cell (51264000000 = 3.840.000.000)  I'm pretty sure Excel is not the right tool for that. Try switching to R or Python

yes F&B&B - the operations are in the cpp compiled function in the dll - I'm using excel to display the results - I mentioned the operation count to note that the dll calls take a bit of time so the excel macro spends quite a lot of time waiting for evaluations to complete. As you can see in the macro, excel does not have to do a lot itself. I would suspect the dll, except that it evaluates all the function calls correctly, but that does not eliminate memory issues in the dll? Its excel that hangs though, and does it after all the function calls are completed... But prob right that its the dll

I see your point, but because the issue is related to the dll you use, we cannot reproduce the problem in our computers and check for a solution. Any given hint or answer probably will be like shooting in the darkness.

@FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns - you were quite right and I was blaming the symptom not looking for my bug... It was a small dynamic array that was left un- delete[] -ed that ran through the memory when calling many times... Thank you for pointing me back to where I needed to look! Do I mark comments as solutions?

Glad you found a solution. You cannot mark any comment as solution but you can answer your own question that may help future users. Just try to detail where the fail was and how did you fixed it and accept your own answer.

OK - Thank you @foxfire-and-burns-and-burns . I was convinced that the problem was with excel and they pointed out that I should look at the cpp-compiled dll that I was calling from VBA as neuman72ForEXL(...) in the VBA of my question. It was a memory leak in a sub function that got called very many (>billion) times and eventually used up available resources and crashed:
'''
v = new double[n]; // allocate the array length n
'''
needed
'''
delete[] v; // free array at end to prevent memory leak
'''
Always need to be skeptical of my own coding and remember that the Excel team are less likely to distribute bugs!
